# d3 data inheritance while append

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

I have two divs: One for pinned charts (#pinned_graphs) and one (#vis) for other charts.

I am successful to pin charts and move them to the #pinned_graphs, but when i try to unpin to move that chart back to the #vis div, during append the chart inherits all the data from the #vis.

below is my code snippet:
Any help is much appreciated, I have done a lot of googling, the issue i think is is with data inheritance during selection.

```
function pin_clicked(d){

 var pinned_icon = d3.select(this).text();
 var div_pinned=d3.select(this.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode);

 if (pinned_icon== '\uf0d3'){ // if icon is pin then pin

   div_pinned.style("position","relative").style("left",0).style("top",0);
   // to move the selected div to the pinned area
   d3.select('#pinned_graphs').append(function(){return div_pinned.node();});
   d3.select(this).text(function(d) { return '\uf118'; });
  }

  else if(pinned_icon== '\uf118'){ //else if icon is unpin, move it back 
    d3.select(this.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode).datum([])
    var div_pinned1=d3.select(this.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode);
    div_pinned1.style("position","absolute")
    var x = div_pinned1.data()[0]
    console.log(div_pinned1)
    d3.select('#vis').append(function(){return div_pinned1.node();}) 
     // if I comment this append line, the data with div_pinned1 is only one object which is what i need
    d3.select(this).text(function(d) { return '\uf0d3'; })

 }

 // re-arrange the charts inside the vis div
    $('#vis').isotope('reloadItems'); 
    return $("#vis").isotope({
      sortBy: 'name'
    });


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to solve the problem for time being, but i have no idea why it is working. any explanation will be great

```
I removed:d3.select(this.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode).datum([])

and added .datum(x) to the append -> d3.select('#vis').datum(x).append(function(){return div_pinned1.node();})
```